# Investing books for the European Union

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, european-union, europe, books

I have read 2 books about investing, and they both assume you are `US` citizen and all the theory and examples they give are about the `US` market.

I have investigated, and I have found that the majority of books are similar in that aspect.

I find that there are a lot of concepts of these books that you can't apply to the `EU`. For instance, `EU` doesn't have something exactly equal to the `S&P 500` (`Euro STOXX 50` is no way as diversified as `S&P 500`), and it is going through a period of extremely political uncertainty, it's definitely not the same as the `US` in terms of investment policies.

I have seen a couple of books about investing in the `EU`, but they doesn't seem very trustworthy.

I'm not interested in any particular european country, but in the whole `EU`.

Is there any good book about investing in the `EU`, with its particularities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a private investor, you'd be better off looking for an investment book focusing on specific countries. Most investing is handled through national law (e.g. taxation) or specific exchanges. A general book about Investing in Europe would likely not cover the particularities of your target country as well as a dedicated book, doubly so for political uncertainties. BREXIT has a vastly different effect on the UK compared to Lithuania. Currencies between countries within Europe (and the European Union) can differ and may introduce added risk.

There are, however, European indices that are somewhat comparable to the S&P500, if you are looking for a general and broad Europe-wide diversification for index investment(e.g. the EURO STOXX 50).

Comment: I'm not interested in any particular european country, I would like to invest in the whole UE market. With regards tou EURO STOXX 50, yes I have read about that, but it contains only 50 companies. It's way different than the S&P in terms of diversification.

Comment: There are other fun indices, e.g. the "MSCI Europe Index" covering 450 Europe-wide companies. It just depends what you are looking for. And while you want to invest in the whole market of the European Union, the stock you are picking will be based in a specific country and currency (e.g. France and Euro), you will have to pay taxes in a specific country (e.g. Spain) and the exchange you pick will be located in a specific country/city (e.g. Frankfurt). The general investment advice of (US-centric) investment books otherwise still applies, it's those specific, important parameters that differ.

Comment: 'the stock you are picking will be based in a specific country and currency' --- but the currency is the same, so there are no problems with that, right?    'the exchange you pick will be located in a specific country/city (e.g. Frankfurt)' --- is that a problem?

Comment: Stocks can be based in USD, EUR, GBP, CHF etc. You will introduce foreign-exchange risk, if this does not equal the currency of your home country, i.e. where you may want to spend that cash. If your stock runs in GBP and the Pound nosedives in relation to the Euro, you may lose value, if your everyday spending is in Euro (not necessarily 1 to 1 depending on the currency of the underlying assets). The location may matter in regards to the laws the company issuing the stock is bound to. The location of the stock exchange may matter, e.g. if there is a transaction tax to be paid.